# Python skimage.io

Tags: python

I am trying to run this script using python (importing a library)

import skimage.io

```
But i get  the following error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\seo_dwarf\chl_scripts\telika\ship_detection.py", line 2, in <module>
    import skimage.io
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 167, in <module>
    from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .apply_parallel import apply_parallel
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\apply_parallel.py", line 8, in <module>
    import dask.array as da
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dask\array\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .core import (Array, block, concatenate, stack, from_array, store,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 46, in <module>
    from ..bytes.core import get_mapper, get_fs_token_paths
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dask\bytes\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core import read_bytes, open_files
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dask\bytes\core.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compression import seekable_files, files as compress_files
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dask\bytes\compression.py", line 31, in <module>
    compress['snappy'] = snappy.compress
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compress'
```

But when i do just import skimage.io in the idle i don t get any errors.

Any ideas how to fix the error?

Comment: Can you please provide the code.

Comment: Did you check if IDLE and terminal are using the same environment? For example, the same version of python.

Comment: how i can check if they use  the same environment? For example if i open command window and press python i get the same as the one using from idle.